# Compiler error C2440

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, compiler-errors

I am getting error c2440 in my compiler but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

This is the error:

```
Error 2 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'System::String ^'   c:\users\***.****\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\cpas1\cpas1\Form1.h 1083
```

and this is the relevant code:

```
String *strFilename = 0;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed types, when used in Managed C++, don't use stars (i.e. *), instead I believe they are called tracking handles (i.e. ^).
As such your statement should be written like this:

```cpp
String^ strFilename = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String *strFilename = "0";
```

not

```
String *strFilename = 0;
```

Comment: C++/CLI tag and mention of ^ in the error message tell me these really aren't pointers, they're handles. Initializing to 0 is not going to be good.

Answer (score 2):

System::String is a managed class. You must use `nullptr` keyword, I believe, to initialize it.